# Unknown layer type: nn.SpatialReplicationPadding

Tags: caffe, torch

When I use (fb-caffe-exts)[https://github.com/zhanghang1989/fb-caffe-exts] to convert torch model to caffe model. It throws an exception:

> Unknown layer type: nn.SpatialReplicationPadding

Anyone can help me? I'm totally confused with it.  The software fb-caffe-exts was installed correctly.

Comment: the caffe convertor does not support this layer for conversion

Comment: Thanks.By the way,could you give some advice about how to add this layer?If you have some example code ,that's the best.